# COUNTing IS NULL returns 0 or with an Error [BigQuery]

Tags: sql, null

I want to find the number of data that is NULL but i do not know why this code returns an error: (Error Message said there was a problem with my WHERE)

```
SELECT first_review, COUNT (1) AS firstreviewisnull
FROM [table_name]
GROUP BY first_review
WHERE first_review IS NULL
```

I tried this code and the count returns to 0 - which I know is incorrect:

```
SELECT COUNT(first_review) AS firstreviewisnull
FROM [table_name]
WHERE first_review IS NULL
```

If possible, please help to:

- explain what i did wrong
- provide with the correct code

thank you!

Comment: 1) The WHERE clause is evaluated _before_ the column alias is created.

Comment: 2) COUNT() never returns null. It returns an integer value, 0 or greater.

Comment: 3) WHERE goes before GROUP BY. Use HAVING clause for aggregate function conditions.

Comment: In your 2nd query, use `COUNT(1)`. `COUNT(first_review)` doesn't count `NULL`, which is precicely what you want to count

Comment: @jarlh thank you.  for 2) i dont expect COUNT() to return NULL, i want it to count the number of NULLs in first_review column. Forgot to note that first_review is a DATE datatype. I will check out your 3).

Comment: thank you @HoneyBadger your answer works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS firstreviewisnull
FROM [table_name]
WHERE first_review IS NULL
```

Count() function ignores Null values (it does not count them). Use count(*) if you want to count the rows where girst_review is null.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL in the second image seems correct, assuming the [table_name] is actually replaced with the proper table name?

Also, check that the values for first_review are actually null, and not an empty String “”, which is not NULL.